# What is this growing in my garden? I planted a bird and butterfly mix and there are several of these. I cannot identify it

Tags: identification, seedlings, wildflowers

[image: plant]

Are these the same plant or are they different ones? We live in South Georgia, sandy and fertilized dirt.

There are 50 or more of these growing and some look incredibly similar and then others look vastly different

[image: more plant]